# How to align datagrid rows

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, alignment

At the moment, I have a datagrid which is bound to a dataset. The datagrid, simply shows rows with the numbers 1-90 in increasing order.

currently it lists all the rows in one real long column. Is it possible to make it start a new column on every tenth row, or would I just have to create ten columns with 9 rows?

My XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Bingo_Game.MainGame"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainGame" Height="500" Width="700">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="grid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="244" Width="672" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HeadersVisibility="None" />
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

c#

```
namespace Bingo_Game
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainGame.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainGame : Window
    {
        public MainGame()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("myDS");
            DataTable numbersTable = new DataTable("Numbers");
            numbersTable.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(Int16));
            for (int i = 1; i < 91; i++)
            {
                numbersTable.Rows.Add(i);
            }
            dataSet.Tables.Add(numbersTable);
            grid.DataContext = numbersTable.DefaultView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want the change the orientation of the DataGrid?

Comment: I tried to explain it best I can. Not really change the orientation. it just list 1-90 at the mo in one long column, i want to make that start a new line/column every tenth row.

Comment: Take a look at the WrapPanel. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I put the wrap panel tags around my datagrid tag and it did nothing

Comment: Yeah, guess not seeing as no answers hey. thanks tho

Comment: Upload your ViewModel and allow us to run your example. Then I ll gladly provide you an answer. What am I suppose to do with those few lines of code you posted? Give us more

Comment: Fair point mate. Ill do that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <DataGrid.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </DataGrid.ItemsPanel>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding WhatEver}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The key is to use a WrapPanel as the ItemsPanel and disable the vertical scrollbar.

As to start a new column at every tenth row, you just need to adjust the height of your DataGrid until it wraps at the tenth row.

Comment: Thanks, this led me to as the bast to finding the answer, thanks.